# Expire server side access token in short period

Tags: facebook-graph-api

recently we encountered some strange behavior of server side access token. It expires in very short period (about 15 min). Scenario is following: User login to our page via facebook (server side) and we store access token. Some actions on our page can trigger post /feed. After few feed posts we suddenly started to getting error 400 and error 401.

Error 400 is probably due to limit of number of posts, but after error 401 access token becomes expired.

Every action respond with:

```
 {
   "error": {
       "message": "Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix 
                   time 1346321603. The current unix time is 1346320983.", 
       "type": "OAuthException", 
       "code": 190
       "error_subcode": 463
   }
```

Its hard to reproduce this behavior but we reproduced it couple of times on test environment (so we know when access token is created, that user didn't deauthorize app, nor change password).

Any ideas why access token becomes expired?

Comment: Did the user maybe just __log out__ of Facebook? Short-term access tokens _will_ expire on that happening.

Comment: No its not - as I said in post we used server side tokens (expires after 60 days) - other tokens are working ok during longer time period

Answer (score 1):

By default facebook assigns a short lived access token. You need to request for long lived token.

Read the doc for how to get it : http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#extend_token

**EDIT:**

Previous link doesn't work anymore, use following link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal/

Comment: As i sad we used server side tokens which expires after 60 days.

Answer (score 1):

I double check that "Remove offline_access permission" was enabled on application advanced settings so i can get 60 days server side token.

Not sure why, but all access token have expire "in about hour" reported from access token debugger.

I created new application (also with "Remove offline_access permission") and now i got tokens which expires in 2 months.

Not sure why, but answer was to create new application.